# How to check the highest score among specific columns and compute the average in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Help with homework problem: "Let us define the "data science experience" of a given person as the person's largest score among Regression, Classification, and Clustering. Compute the average data science experience among all MSIS students."

Beginner to coding. I am trying to figure out how to check amongst columns and compare those columns to each other for the largest value. And then take the average of those found values.

I greatly appreciate your help in advance!

Picture of the sample data set:  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRjmr.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OSjz.png

```
Provided Code: 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("cleaned_survey.csv", index_col=0)
df.drop(['ProgSkills','Languages','Expert'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Sample Data: 
[image]

What I have tried so far:

```
df[data_science_experience]=df[["Regression","Classification","Clustering"]].values.max()
df['z']=df[['Regression','Classification','Clustering']].apply(np.max,axis=1)
df[data_science_experience]=df[["Regression","Classification","Clustering"]].apply(np.max,axis=1)
```

Comment: Which columns do you want to compare, and what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: First, Don't post image as input, it's hard to reproduce your sample. Second, clearly explain your problem with minimal example. provide sample input and expected output. for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Most importantly show us what have you tried so far, and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: @MarcusLim I want to compare columns 'Regression', 'Classification', and 'Clustering' for the largest value amongst those three columns for only students in Program 'MSIS'. And then take the average of those values.

Comment: @MarcusLim I want to compare those three columns amongst each other for the largest score. Not the largest score out of all values in each column. I want to compare the columns in a single row. Let me know if that clarifies it?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah I have updated the data sample. I copied and pasted the data into the website and what is shown is what resulted. It pasted automatically as such. Please let me know if thats better?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah I have updated what I have been trying as well. Basically trying to get the max value of those columns when compared each other in a row. But rows for only students in the column Program 'MSIS'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the highest score of column 'hw1' you can get it with:
`pd['hw1'].max()`. 
this gives you a series of all the values in that column and max returns the maximum. for average use mean:

`pd['hw1'].mean()`

if you want to find the maximum of multiple columns, you can use:

```
maximum_list = list()
for col in pd.columns:
    maximum_list.append(pd[col].max)
max = maximum_list.max()
avg = maximum_list.mean()
```

hope this helps.

Comment: I would like to compare the columns amongst each other within a row? And only the rows for students in the  'MSIS' program. I want the highest value within the row for those columns.

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to get only the rows with `MSIS` in the `Program` column. That can be done in the following way:

`df[df['Program'] == 'MSIS']`

Next, you want to get only the `Regression`, `Classification` and `Clustering` columns. The previous query filtered only rows; we can add to that, like this:

`df.loc[df['Program'] == 'MSIS', ['Regression', 'Classification', 'Clustering']]`

Now, for each row remaining, we want to take the maximum. That can be done by appending `.max(axis=1)` to the previous line (`axis=1` because we want the maximum of each row, not each column).

At this point, we should have a DataFrame where each row represents the highest score of the three categories for each student. Now, all that's left to do is take the mean, which can be done with `.mean()`. The full code should therefore look like this:

```
df.loc[df['Program'] == 'MSIS', ['Regression', 'Classification', 'Clustering']].max(axis=1).mean()
```